# 64 bit Windows 7 and driver installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, cpu, dell-optiplex

I am planning to install the 64 bit version of Windows 7 OS and just wanted to confirm if the OS would install the drivers for my system automatically or I'll have to install them manually after the OS installation?

**My System Details**
***Processor***
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz, 2394 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

***System Manufacturer***
Dell Inc.

***System Model***
OptiPlex 755

Comment: possible duplicate of [should you install specific drivers from your motherboard / video card manufacturer, or let Windows do the job?](http://superuser.com/questions/657512/should-you-install-specific-drivers-from-your-motherboard-video-card-manufactu), http://superuser.com/questions/333526/why-should-i-install-hardware-drivers-if-my-computer-is-working-fine, also see: http://superuser.com/questions/621899/installing-drivers-after-the-os-reinstallation

Comment: It has a standard INTEL chipset go to intel.com and download the newest version.  Windows 7 will install a version of drivers, but likely a couple will be missing.  Most will need updating.

Answer (score 1):

The OS should install some generic drivers in order for you to be able to use the machine, at first.

These should work and get you started, but it is recommended that you install the drivers provided by the manufacturer or equipment supplier.

You can find the drivers here: [Click me!!!](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/optiplex-755)

Comment: Well, I checked for the Windows 7 64 bit drivers for my machine at your provided link. They don't have for Windows 7 listed in their OS dropdown. Where should I find the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated several of our older Dell machines, including 1 optiplex, to Win7-64. Microsoft update has done an excellent job of installing all the drivers and all the machines are running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If after the installation of 64 bit Windows 7 there are devices left out without drivers, you could let Windows search automatically for updated driver software (make sure you enable the feature in the device installation setting). If this fails, and since Dell did not provide drivers for Windows 7 for your PC model you could try to look for drivers from the manufacturer of that particular device. If this likewise fails, your last option would be to try the 64bit Windows Vista drivers available on the link provided above and hope they work.